# Fast Ai: AttributeError: 'Learner' object has no attribute 'fine_tune'

Tags: fast-ai

Fast Ai uses a very unconventional style of `from fastai import *` etc.

I for one do not like it so was painstakingly identifying each import in the [chapter 2 of the fastai book](https://github.com/fastai/fastbook/blob/master/02_production.ipynb) but ran into the error

```
AttributeError: 'Learner' object has no attribute 'fine_tune'
```

However, when I then go and do

```
from fastbook import *
```

it works. This is a very odd behavior in that something is done to the cnn_learner class or the module that contains it making it have the fine_tune method if the above import is done.

I would like to avoid this style of coding, so what should I do to load the correct version of Learner?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just faced the exact same issue. After looking at one of their tutorial I saw that the cnn learner is not imported from the expected package.

```py
from fastai.vision.all import cnn_learner
# rather than
from fastai.vision.learner import cnn_learner
```

calling the `fine_tune` method then works as expected !

Answer (score 5):

Fastai does a lot of monkey patching. Not only to its own imports but also to other libraries such as `pathlib` or `torch`. I personally don't like this style of coding either but it is what it is.

I would highly recommend creating a separate environment (e.g. through conda), install fastai there and use their `from ... import *`. I have tried to work around these imports in the past but since you don't know (unless you dig into source) where/what has been monkey patched, you will be running into `missing attribute` and similar errors all over the place.

Also, it doesn't play nice with some other libraries. I remember having hard time making it work with `opencv` due to package dependencies, where installing `opencv` broke some of the fastai's functionality (which I have only found later) due to overriding something that has been patched by fastai in some external library.

Comment: Reminds me of why I switched to Python from Perl